# CrystalReportViewer.SelectionFormula IN() function

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, crystal-reports

Is ther any way to do something like this :

```
crview.SelectionFormula = "report.Field IN (2,3,4,5)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the selection formula would be

```
"{report.Field} IN [2,3,4,5]"
```